# Error with net.forward() in OpenCV EAST text detector in pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I am trying EAST text detector in pycharm but there is an error at line.
`(scores, geometry) = net.forward(layerNames)`

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\concat_layer.cpp:95: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) Inconsistent shape for ConcatLayer in function 'cv::dnn::ConcatLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'
```

CODE:

```
print("[INFO] loading EAST text detector...")
name = 'Pictures/non crop/maths soln analysis 4_89.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(name, 1)
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
```

set the new width and height and then determine the ratio in change
for both the width and height

```
(newW, newH) = (375, 500)
rW = W / float(newW)
rH = H / float(newH)
# resize the image and grab the new image dimensions
image = cv2.resize(image, (newW, newH))
orig = image.copy()
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("frozen_east_text_detection.pb")
layerNames = [
"feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid",
"feature_fusion/concat_3"]
```

construct a blob from the image and then perform a forward pass of
the model to obtain the two output layer sets

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (W, H),
(123.68, 116.78, 103.94), swapRB=True, crop=False)
start = time.time()
net.setInput(blob)
```

## ERROR at this line

```
(scores, geometry) = net.forward(layerNames)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not [resizing to a multiple of 32](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/).

> Important: The EAST text requires that your input image dimensions be multiples of 32, so if you choose to adjust your --width  and --height  values, make sure they are multiples of 32!

Answer (score 2):

When the size is the same, this error does not occur ; but when the size is changed, for example from 320x320 to 640x640, then it does occur.
This problem doesn't have anything to do with resizing to a multiple of 32.

640x640 is two multiples of 32, but the error still appears.

`320x320: OK`, then `640x640: Inconsistent shape for ConcatLayer`

Comment: Did you ever find any information about why this error would be caused?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
(newW, newH) = (375, 500)
```

to

```
(newW, newH) = (320,320)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple run this command in the terminal:

```
python text_detection.py --image images/car_wash.png --east frozen_east_text_detection.pb
```